# Joining Multiple Queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have 3 similar MySQL queries shown below which take the average temperatures for segments of time and group them by cities. I want to return 1 table with 4 columns: city, avg_morning_temp, avg_day_temp, and avg_night_temp. How can I do this?

```
SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_morning_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:59:59'
GROUP BY city;

SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_day_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:59:59'
GROUP BY city;

SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_night_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '23:59:59'
GROUP BY city;
```

I tried joining them like shown below, it wasn't successful.

```
(SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_morning_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:59:59'
GROUP BY city) AS avg_morning_temp

JOIN avg_day_temp USING city

(SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_day_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:59:59'
GROUP BY city) AS avg_day_temp

JOIN avg_night_temp USING city

(SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG(temperature), 2) AS avg_night_temp
FROM weather
WHERE TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '23:59:59'
GROUP BY city) AS avg_night_temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `JOIN`, a simple `CASE` statement should work.

Try:

```
SELECT
    city,
    ROUND(AVG( case when TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '07:59:59' then temperature end ), 2) AS avg_morning_temp,
    ROUND(AVG( case when TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '15:59:59' then temperature end ), 2) AS avg_day_temp,
    ROUND(AVG( case when TIME(datetime) BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '23:59:59' then temperature end ), 2) AS avg_night_temp
FROM weather
GROUP BY city;
```